# Create Active Directory users with certain attributes in a script

Tags: if-statement, active-directory, powershell-ise

I'm working on a PowerShell script to make it easier to create Active Directory users including some attributes. For now I need to process the "Manager" field. We have 4 departments, 4 managers. I want to create this using logic like "if department is 1 of the 4 departments then give 1 of the 4 managers."

How can I process this?

```
Import-Module activedirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv "c:\temp\scripts\ADUsers.csv"

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below

    $Firstname  = $User.firstname
    $Lastname   = $User.lastname
    $Username   = $User.username
    $Password   = $User.password
    $OU         = $User.ou #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be created in
    $userprincipalname = $user.userprincipalname
    $displayname = $user.displayname
    $title = $user.jobtitle
    $department = $user.department

    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
    {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-host 
        #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account
        #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
    New-ADUser -Name $displayname -SamAccountName $Username -UserPrincipalName $userprincipalname  -GivenName $Firstname -Surname $Lastname -Enabled $True -DisplayName $displayname -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) 
    }
} #end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if ($department -eq "A")
{
    $manager = "ManagerA"
}
else if ($department -eq "B")
{
    $manager = "ManagerB"
}
else if ($department -eq "C")
{
    $manager = "ManagerC"
}
else if ($department -eq "D")
{
    $manager = "ManagerD"
}

New-ADUser -Name $displayname -SamAccountName $Username -UserPrincipalName $userprincipalname  -GivenName $Firstname -Surname $Lastname -Enabled $True -DisplayName $displayname -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Manager $manager
```

"ManagerA/B/C/D" are SAM account name of user objects of managers.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with a Switch like below.

```
Switch ($department) {
    "dept 1" {$manager = "cn=jim smith,ou=west,dc=domain,dc=com"}
    "dept 2" {$manager = "cn=sally wilson,ou=east,dc=domain,dc=com"}
    "dept 3" {$manager = "cn=frank johnson,ou=east,dc=domain,dc=com"}
    "dept 4" {$manager = "cn=mary tutle,ou=west,dc=domain,dc=com"}
```